# How to read innerText from the projected node in Angular 2

Tags: angular

To have a component like this:

```
<copy [value]="model.Property"></copy>
```

You write:

```
var copy = ng.core.Component({
    selector: 'copy',
    inputs: ['value'],
    template: '<button mdTooltip="copy" md-icon-button attr.copy="{{ value }}"><md-icon>content_copy</md-icon></button>'
}).Class({
    constructor: function (element) {

    }
});
```

What if you want to use your component like this:

```
<copy>{{ model.Property }}</copy>
```

I can't make it work. How to read value from an innerText of interpolated expression?

Comment: hey, did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44560492/2545680) help?

Answer (score 1):

What you specify between a component tags is called projected nodes and the process is called [node projection](https://toddmotto.com/transclusion-in-angular-2-with-ng-content#angular-content-projection).

```
<copy>{{ model.Property }}</copy>
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    projected content (nodes)
```

This is the terminology from the web components and shadow DOM domain. Angular supports node projection inside the components template through `ng-content` tag. To achieve what you're trying to do you will have to use `ng-content` inside the `copy` component template, wait for the projected content nodes initialization, access this node using `@ContentChildren` and read the `innerText`. Something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'copy',
  template: '...<ng-content></ng-content>...'
})
class CopyComponent {
  @ContentChild('v') projected;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
     console.log(this.projected.nativeElement.innerText); // 'some value'
  }
}

@Component({
   selector: 'parent',
   templates: '...<copy><span #v>{{prop}}</span></copy>...'
})
class Parent {
  prop = 'some value';
}
```

I used TS, but it can easily be adapted for JS.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <copy>{{ model.Property }}</copy>
```

this is a one way interpolation , one way binding of value from component to HTML.

**model** will be your object variable  in component with public scope.

any value change in model.Property will be directly interpolated to DOM.

IF you need to have two way binding ( update from DOM to be reflected in component , below is the syntax

```
<copy [(ngModel)] = "model.Property"></copy>
```